# Proper name for a thermodynamic process with constant internal energy $U$

Tags: thermodynamics, soft-question, terminology

Back in the day I learned that a few special thermodynamical processes have special names.

For example, if one keeps $P$ constant, the process is called isobaric, if one keeps $T, V$ or $S$ constant, one gets, correspondingly, isothermic, isochoric or isentropic processes. Similarly, if one keeps $\dfrac{\mathrm{d} \ln P}{\mathrm{d} \ln \rho}$ constant during the process, it is called polytropic, and if $\delta Q = 0$ at any time, the process is called adiabatic.

Now, the question: what is the process called, if one keeps internal energy $U$ constant?

Comment: @Danu, "isentropic" is typically used for hydrodynamical flows, rather than processes. Though I do agree that adiabatic is a bit more general (I add a specification).

Comment: When the energy is kept constant, the process is called isoenergetic (or, if you prefer, iso-energetic).

Comment: Notice that if there is some subtlety and you keep a constant internal energy $U=\text{cte}$ but not a constant energy $E=U+E_{\text{m}}$, by modifying the mechanical energy $E_{\text{m}}$, you should refrain from using standard names like isoenergetic and explain precisely what happens.

Comment: Dear @GeorgSievelson, thank you, this is exactly what I have been looking for! For completeness, would the term be suitable for flows, which keep specific internal energy constant (remembering your other comment, though)?

Comment: I would also gladly consider it as an answer, if you can apply a comment->answer transformation to your reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A process where the energy is kept constant is called isoenergetic (or, if you prefer, iso-energetic). 
It also seems from the literature that a flow where the energy is constant when following a fluid particle is usually called an *isoenergetic flow*.

Similarly, when the enthalpy is kept constant, the process (or the flow) is said to be isenthalpic (or isoenthalpic). And so on.

Notice that if there is some subtlety and you keep a constant internal energy $U=\text{cte}$ but not a constant energy $E=U+E_{\text{m}}$, by modifying the mechanical energy $E_{\text{m}}$, you should refrain from using standard names like isoenergetic and explain precisely what happens.

Answer (score -1):

The process with constant internal energy is called free expansion.

Comment: There is a constant temperature for ideal gas - isothermic process, I am not sure it is the same https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_expansion and look at the internal energy definition - if temperature is constant, V changes and U hanges - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_energy - Recheck please.